# Dropdownlist in templatefield - update fails (null value insertion)

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, drop-down-menu, edititemtemplate

I have a gridview. In this i have a templatefield with a DropDownList (DDL in EditItemTemplate mode, label in ItemTemplate mode).
When i hit edit on of of the detailsview's rows i can select any value from the DDL (the DDL is populated from a sqldatasource), but if i try to execute the update, it fails, because it thinks i didn't supply the data...

Here is the exact error (the DB refuse NULL data):

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'status', table
>   'gyumolcs.dbo.orders'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Here is the code for the gridview:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="orderadminSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dotnetConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT orders.ID, aspnet_Users.UserName, orders.quantity AS Quantity, product.name AS Product, status.name AS Status, orders.date AS Date FROM orders INNER JOIN product ON orders.ordertype = product.ID INNER JOIN status ON orders.status = status.ID INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON orders.userid = aspnet_Users.UserId ORDER BY date" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM orders WHERE (ID = @ID)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE orders SET status = @status WHERE (ID = @ID)">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="status" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="orderadminSqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="ID" Width="608px" 
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="15">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
                SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Felhasználónév" 
                SortExpression="UserName" >
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Mennyiség (kg)" 
                SortExpression="Quantity" >
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Termék" 
                SortExpression="Product" >
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rendelés státusz" SortExpression="status">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <!--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>-->

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="statustypeDDLSqlDataSource" DataTextField="name"
                        DataValueField="ID">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="statustypeDDLSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dotnetConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [name] FROM [status]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Dátum" SortExpression="Date" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="15" Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the orderadminSqlDataSource's code (the gridview's datasource)

```
<!-- language: c# -->
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="orderadminSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dotnetConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT orders.ID, aspnet_Users.UserName, orders.quantity AS Quantity, product.name AS Product, status.name AS Status, orders.date AS Date FROM orders INNER JOIN product ON orders.ordertype = product.ID INNER JOIN status ON orders.status = status.ID INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON orders.userid = aspnet_Users.UserId ORDER BY date" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM orders WHERE (ID = @ID)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE orders SET status = @status WHERE (ID = @ID)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="status" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Please help me, i can't figure out the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're forgetting to set the DropDown's `SelectedValue` property:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"
                  runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="statustypeDDLSqlDataSource"
                  DataTextField="name"
                  DataValueField="status"
                  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("status") %>'
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
```

Change your code for `statustypeDDLSqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="statustypeDDLSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dotnetConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] as status, [name] FROM [status]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can also simplify this ( no parenthesis necessary ):

```
UPDATE orders SET [status] = @status WHERE [ID] = @ID
```

Note: I had to rename the ID column in the query so that it conforms with the `status` parameter you defined here:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="status" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

**My last edit and attempt here :D**

After carefully looking at your GridView's `SELECT` statement I see where the error lies:

```
SELECT orders.ID,
       aspnet_Users.UserName,
       orders.quantity AS Quantity,
       product.name AS Product,
       status.name AS Status,
       orders.date AS Date
FROM orders
INNER JOIN product ON
orders.ordertype = product.ID
INNER JOIN status ON orders.status = status.ID
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON orders.userid = aspnet_Users.UserId
ORDER BY date
```

Change it to:

```
SELECT orders.ID,
       aspnet_Users.UserName,
       orders.quantity AS Quantity,
       product.name AS Product,
       status.ID AS status,
       status.name AS StatusName,
       orders.date AS Date
FROM orders
INNER JOIN product ON
orders.ordertype = product.ID
INNER JOIN status ON orders.status = status.ID
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON orders.userid = aspnet_Users.UserId
ORDER BY date
```

Now you must change this part too:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StatusName") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

---

By the way... here's a nice step by step tutorial on this matter:

[Walkthrough: Displaying a Drop-Down List While Editing in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried this without any success. The error i get: "'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value"

Comment: To get rid of this error do this: `DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;` or add this to the markup: `AppendDataBoundItems="True"`

Comment: Without the "<% #Eval("ID")%>" and with the appendDataBoundItem i get the first error (Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'status'...), and with Eval && appenddatabounditems i get the second error (DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid ...)

Comment: Try Bind instead of Eval... :)

Comment: With Bind + appendData... still "'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value" error. now i'm reading the tutorial you linked, but i see no differences :S

Comment: Leniel, i see you edited your comment ("change your code for statustypeDDLSqlDataSource..."). The problem is this: i need name and ID as well from that table, because in the orders table the "status" column is int. (statuses like: 1 - ordered, 2 - paid, 3 - transferred, etc)

Comment: uhmmm... I see. Let me think about it.

Comment: I changed the code. Now ID in the update parameter refer to the Order ID and status refer to the Status ID.

Comment: Are you sure you changed your code with the bits provided in my answer? You're getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, i'm changed everything, and i'm getting the same error ('DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value).  Here is the code i have now (with the changes): http://pastebin.com/n1h248bU

Comment: Change your select as I did above... :)

Comment: YES! I can say i'm fu**ing dumb!!! :D  Now the update is fine, only 1 last question to you (as i see you a "little bit" experienced in asp.net than i):  now at the column "status" ("Rendelés státusz") i see lots of 1, and 2. But i need to see some "ordered", "paid", etc. How can i do that? I know i have to manipulate the "`<asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>`" but i don't know how.  (the DDL's databind works perfectly, i see "ordered" instead of "1")

Comment: See... I also changed the `ItemTemplate` field... you must bind to the `StatusName` now. No. You're not dumb!!! This happens all the time even with experienced people. :) Have FUN programming because it's all about having fun.

Comment: Works like a charm. You just saved my night, and granted me some sleep. Thanks man!