# How to add record to new nullable columns of existing table by selecting dropdownvalue in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ascx

I updated an existing table in SQL Server by adding 2 new nullable columns. I want to allow the users to add records to these columns by selecting dropdown value. In this page I have another custom server controls which will be saved to the same table, but all controls not under grid view column.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="_Country" Width="31%" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelected">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="USA"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Russia" Value="Russia"></asp:ListItem>

protected void Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Connectionblabla.............=true;");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert  into Cities  (Country) VALUES (@Country)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Country", _country.SelectedItem.Value);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

What code need I write on code behind? Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Add more info on what have you tried so far to achieve the functionality that you are looking for. Any error info and so forth. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you might need to put that dropdown inside a asp:templatefield

Check out this thread!! It might help you

[Update null dropdown values to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421607/dropdownlist-in-templatefield-update-fails-null-value-insertion?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)